# Property 'props' does not exist on type '{}' (trying to get access to props of children) - React Typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm doing custom Tabs component and ran into some problems.

When I try to get access to the 'props' of children I get an error: **Property 'props' does not exist on type '{}'**

```
const Tabs: FC<{
  children: ReactNode[];
}> = ({ children }) => {
  const [activeTab, setActiveTab] = useState<TabLabel | null>(null);
  
  useEffect(() => {
    setActiveTab(children[0]?.props.label);
  }, []);
}
```

I would not be surprised with this error if it appeared in another place where I am traversing the array of children using the map method.

```
{children.map(
          (child) =>
            isValidElement(child) && (
              <button
                className={cn('checkout-tabs_tab', { '-active': child.props.label === activeTab })}
                key={child.props.label}
                onClick={() => onSetActiveTab(child.props.label)}
                role="tab"
                type="button"
              >
                {child.props.label}
              </button>
            )
 )}
```

The code above **does not give an error** when trying to access props. I know there is a check with `isValidElement` react helper but if I do the same check in the place where I get the error, it gives me another one:

```
useEffect(() => {
    if (isValidElement(children[0])) {
      setActiveTab(children[0]?.props.label);
    }
 }, []);
```

// **TS2571: Object is of type 'unknown'.**

I'm kinda new to typescript/react and would be glad to have this behavior explained to me. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this generic with expected Props

```
FC<{ children: ReactElement<TabItemProps>[] }>
```

Comment: Thanks, working perfect. Now everything fell into place and I can even get rid of checking with `isValidElement` helper.

`const Tabs: FC<{
  children: ReactElement<TabItem>[];
}> `